# Vector field Stream?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, vector, streams

The following graph shows the vector plot. How can I plot the solid lines which represents how the vectors are spatially varying and both on the same graph (vector plot and stream field)?

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[
Evaluate[Grad[{z - Sin[2 \[Pi] y] Cos[\[Pi] x]}, {x, y, 
 z}]], {"XStackedPlanes", 2}, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here are the streamlines using the centers of the arrows in the vector plot as initial conditions:

```
svp = SliceVectorPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Grad[{z - Sin[2 π y] Cos[π x]}, {x, y, z}]],
    {"XStackedPlanes", 2}, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1}]

streamline[point_] :=
  Line@Transpose@
    NDSolveValue[{{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == 
       First@(Grad[{z - Sin[2 π y] Cos[π x]}, {x, y, z}] /. 
          v : x | y | z :> v[t]), {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == point,
      WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1/2, "StopIntegration"],
      WhenEvent[Abs[y[t] - 1] > 1, "StopIntegration"],
      WhenEvent[Abs[z[t] - 1/2] > 1/2, "StopIntegration"]},
     Through[{x, y, z}["ValuesOnGrid"]], {t, -10, 10}];

points = Cases[svp, Arrow[a_] :> Mean[a], Infinity];

Show[svp,
 Graphics3D[{Red, streamline /@ points}]
 ]
```

[image]
[image]

There's no [`StreamPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) for 3D, so manual construction is needed.  You can use [`Arrow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html) instead of [`Line`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html) in the definition of `streamline`.  You can also use [`Arrowheads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) to put multiple arrows on them.

Comment: Error occurred during execution in v14.